# basic form methods in WWW::Mechanize not working in WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS

Tags: perl, phantomjs, mechanize, www-mechanize

Using form methods in WWW::Mechanize like

```
    my @form = $mech->form_number(1);
    foreach my $sum_form ( @form ) {
        my @inputfields = $sum_form->param;
         …
     }
```

works fine so far. Using WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS, I get an error like

```
Can't locate object method "param" via package "Selenium::Remote::WebElement" at...
```

The form methods in WWW::Mechanize should be the same in WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS, right? Does anybody know who to solve that issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You should dump this scalar with Data::Dumper, use code below and paste returned text from terminal.

```
my @form = $mech->form_number(1);
foreach my $sum_form ( @form ){
    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper $sum_form;
}
```